# Set default "From" address for all outgoing emails from Salesforce

Tags: email, email2case, emailmessage

The requirement is as follows : Set default "From" address for all outgoing emails. Could someone explain me how this can be done?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set OW email address here. Administer >Email Administration > Organization-Wide Email Addresses.

For the WF you need to set default WF email address under Workflow>Setting.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes i get that. I am sorry that i haven't rephrased my question properly. I need to set Email address based on a logic - say if mail has XYZ subject, it should have a from address of aaa@gmail.com. Logic based setting of FROM address is what i expect. Is that possible?

Comment: i don't think that's natively possible. but in code you can use setReplyTo(replyAddress) of base email class in email send process. hope it helps

Comment: Does it work for all emails going out from salesforce?

Comment: Yes all emails sent from the code.